# Delete cookies for a particular host from javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I delete **all cookies for a particular host**, from javascript.
I have checked the deleteCookie function shared by many, but I am not finding how to delete cookies concerned to a particular domain.(Eg:Delete cookies concerned to host/domain about.com).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: I just want to delete the cookies concerned to localhost. According to the policy, I can do that right ? Origins are same. So in this case, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete cookies which are from the current domain. To delete a cookie, set its expiration time to a time in the past.

Comment: What you mean by 'Current domain' is localhost(own system) ?? If yes, how can I delete it. I know that on setting time to a past time, cookie gets deleted, but am not understanding how to do this for the domain 'localhost' ?

Comment: I mean current domain as in the domain of the web page which is running the Javascript code.

Comment: This is the code which I have given. This aint working. Please help me through !!!                                                           <script type="text/javascript">
var path="/";
var domain="localhost";
var name="LOGIN";


alert("path-->"+path);
alert("domain-->"+domain);
alert("name-->"+name);

if ( Get_Cookie( name ) )
   document.cookie=name+"="+((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
                                   ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";

</script>

Comment: And you copied all that code from the site where you got it, including the function `Get_Cookie`? Did you look in th eerror console to see what error is generated by the code?

Comment: I had changed the code... I know that Get_Cookie() is not present in the code.          <script type="text/javascript">
var path="/";
var domain="localhost";
var name="LOGIN";


function delCookie(name) { 
alert("In delCookie function and name-->"+name);
document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT" + "; path=/"; 
} 
delCookie("LOGIN");

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Javascript.  You can read a cookie's value but you can't see its domain in Javascript.

Comment: We can see all details concerned to a cookie.(Using Mozilla)

Comment: Can you see those details in javascript?  If so please post code.

Comment: Using mozilla, go to Tools/Options/Show Cookies, and it will show cookies created for each domain. On clicking on any of them, it will show you the details.

Comment: Your question was "Delete cookies for a particular host FROM JAVASCRIPT."  My answer was that "I don't think this is possible WITH JAVASCRIPT."  If you know how to do it WITH JAVASCRIPT please post code.